# HighCharts Export burger menu not showing in AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I've an AngularJS app rendered by ASP.net MVC. AngularJS is using HighCharts (not highcharts-ng though). I've below script references:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>
```

And, I've below in chart options:

```
exporting: {
  enabled: true,
  chartOptions: { // specific options for the exported image
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  scale: 1,
  fallbackToExportServer: true
}
```

Yet, the export burger menu is not showing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is this your full json  Are you using Angular or jquery?  Just adding exporting.js is sufficient to show the burger menu.  exporting.enabled is true by default.

Comment: @Mahesh This is not the full JSON. I'm using Angular (though jquery is referenced). Exactly! From what I read just adding exporting.js should be enough yet the menu is not appearing.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle for the Angular version that works](https://jsfiddle.net/newjavaonemahesh/8h9taawz/), and nothing in fact needs to be done except adding the two exporting*.js.

I have added exporting fragment of the JSON though.  But omitting that part also brings up the burger.  You may want to check with this.  No jQuery is required, I take that statement back.  Direct use of the API inside the controller, that's all.

> in the controller:

```
        angular.module('myModule', [])
          .controller('myController', function($scope) {
            Highcharts.chart('container', {
              title: {
            text: 'Temperature Data'
              },

              xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
              'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
            ]
              },

              series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
              }],
              exporting: {
          enabled: true,
          chartOptions: { // specific options for the exported image
            plotOptions: {
              series: {
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: false
            }
              }
            }
          },
          scale: 1,
          fallbackToExportServer: true
        }
            });
          });
```

**Also check if the exporting.js loads over https.**

Comment: Mahesh & @Sajeetharan: all the examples I've seen so far render highcharts right upon loading. Where as the setup I've is, a landing page is shown, if the user clicks Chart link then ChartCtrlr renders the chart. Could this delayed loading of chart be causing the burger menu not to display? Just wondering...

Comment: Can't tell without knowing what your routes look like.  **[This is an updated plunkr which uses ngRoute](http://plnkr.co/edit/6CxZm2iyDIFdAkgnlttd?p=preview)** - shows home page with a link.  When you click shows the graph.  I believe it is closer to your usecase.  You can see the burger with no issue.  You may also want to check if there is some style issue hiding the burger.

Comment: **[this is an updated plunkr which uses state router instead of ngRoute](http://plnkr.co/edit/5CFNErwKci2U85pnTZIM?p=preview)**  Again in theory, view change *should not* affect rendering.

Comment: Yup. It is the CSS messing with this burger menu. I commented all css reference and burger shows fine. Now, I need to see exactly which style is causing this. Thanks to you & @Sajeetharan